# Equivalent of FileSystemObject.OpenTextFile(fileName, ForReading) in c#

Tags: c#, .net, vba, c#-to-vb.net

I want to convert following vb code to c#

```
Public Function ReadATextFile(fileName As String) As String
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim Tsr As TextStream
Dim ReturnString  As String

 If FSO.FileExists(fileName) Then
     Set Tsr = FSO.OpenTextFile(fileName, ForReading)
            ReturnString = Tsr.ReadAll
            Tsr.Close

 ReadATextFile=ReturnString 

 End If

End Function
```

this routine just reads the file into string using FileSystemObject in VBA

I used the  `string str = File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName); in c#`

but problem here is when i explore the string from the VBA the length of the string is around 13000 and string from the c# the length is around 15000

why such difference? what extra characters are added through c#? Is it depend on encoding, compiler or any other factor...

Comment: You could try to save both files (WriteAllText) for both VBA and C# and diff the changes.

Comment: there is no difference in the content of the both files but when i encrypt the string using same algorithm in both C# and VBA i got the different contents :(

Comment: This function will always return an empty string `""`... Should be pretty easy to write an equivalent in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C# version will use UTF-8 encoding, which may explain the difference.

Try specifying an encoding explicitly, e.g.

```
File.ReadAllText(ofd.FileName, Encoding.Default);
```

`Encoding.Default` is the encoding for the operating system's current ANSI page.  Despite its name, it is not used as the default encoding for most methods that take an optional Encoding parameter.

Comment: yup i used the same but after getting the string ,i encrypt the string using same algorithm in both C# and VBA i got the different contents c# will use UTF-8 then what about VBA what is default encoding of FileSystemObject when we read file

Comment: @kevin159: ",i encrypt the string using same algorithm in both C# and VBA i got the different contents" - I'm not sure I understand what you're getting at here, the code you posted has nothing to do with encryption.  If you post the VBA and C# encryption code, no doubt someone will be able to explain why they give different results.